# Fail to install theme on development copy of WordPress on Webmatrix

Tags: theme-development, themes

I am a newbie on WordPress and the development copy of company WordPress site is running on WebMatrix. One very first thing I try to do is to install a theme to the development copy to make sure it functions correctly. However, I had an error message to say "Could not create directory. `/home/xxx/public_html/companyname/xxx-content/themes/twentyfifteen/`. As I use WebMatrix to open the copy of company WordPress site locally, WebMatrix opens companyname folder directly, therefore new theme installation failed because of incorrect folder path. My question is how do I solve the path issue between what WordPress expects to see, like `/home/xxx/public_html/companyname` and the local site folder's real location, like `companyname` only.

Comment: Seems to me more of an WebMatrix question then WordPress. It could be better answered if moved to Superuser or stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was not sure if the issue is related with WebMatrix then I found it is due to setting of WP_CONTENT_DIR.

Comment: I see. glad you worked it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in WordPress documentation.

By setting [`WP_CONTENT_URL`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_themes_folder) in `wp-config.php` file fixed my problem.